# Use text inputs in (Eonasdan Bootstrap 3) timepicker instead of clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I'm using the excellent eonasdan datetimepicker, when using the timepicker I'd like to be able to write in the hour/minute in the picker itself, instead of using the default function where you for example click the minutes and you can select by 5 minute increments. What I'm looking for is the same functionality as in this timepicker: https://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/ (see first demo, click open the picker and see the text inputs for hour/minute). Is this possible with the eonasdan datetimepicker?

All help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I fear that you have to modify the `eonasdan-datetimepicker` code to get what you need or use a different library, there is no built-in option to get an text input field instead of selectable values.